# Solve for transform parameters given original and transformed vectors

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

I have some transformation in 3D homogeneous coordinates that includes three-axis rotation, translation and strain (linear deformation):

$$\\
T P = P' \\
T = D R_z R_y R_x S
$$

$$
D =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & d_x \\
0 & 1 & 0 & d_y \\
0 & 0 & 1 & d_z \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\\
R_z =
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos a & -\sin a & 0 & 0 \\
\sin a & \cos a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\\
R_y =
\begin{bmatrix}\cos b & 0 & -\sin b & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-\sin b & 0 & \cos b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \\
R_x =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos c & -\sin c & 0 \\
0 & \sin c & \cos c & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \\
S =
\begin{bmatrix}
m_x & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & m_y & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & m_z & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$P$ and $P'$ are identically-sized $4 \times n$, where $n$ is the number of points. I have some control over the number of points, but it should probably be at least 3.

Given $P$ and $P'$, I need to solve for all of the transformation parameters: $a, b, c, d_x, d_y, d_z, m_x, m_y, m_z$. If $n$ is set to 4, then at least $T = P'/P$ is a straightforward matrix inversion, though $n$ might end up being higher and I would probably have to use a pseudoinverse.

I will be using a numerical library (not yet chosen), but for the time being:

- How much of this solution can be done analytically?
- Is there a way of re-forming the problem to make the solution easier? (I considered spherical coordinates but I'm not very sure how I would go about that)

I tried a couple of brute-force numerical multivariate nonlinear solvers on this and they both (unsurprisingly) choked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@dovalojd's answer is pretty good. There are better methods, though, of determining the nautical angles. You can use a test vector to eliminate the roll, $\theta_x$:

$
  \hat n = Q\hat x \\
  = R_z R_y R_x \hat x \\
  = R_z R_y \hat x \\
  = R_z \begin{bmatrix}
      \cos \theta_y \\
      0 \\
      -\sin \theta_y
    \end{bmatrix} \\
  \hat n = \begin{bmatrix}
      \cos \theta_y \cos \theta_z \\
      \cos \theta_y  \sin \theta_z \\
      -\sin \theta_y
    \end{bmatrix}
$

With the roll gone, you can focus on the other two. First, you find the yaw, $\theta_z$, using `yaw = atan2(nx, ny)`. Then you calculate the pitch, $\theta_y$, using `s = hypot(nx, ny); pitch = atan2(s, -nz)`. Though `asin` could be used directly on `ny` since $\theta_y \in [-\frac \tau 4,-\frac \tau 4]$, it is numerically unstable around $\pm \frac \tau 4$, so it should be avoided. `atan2` doesn't suffer this problem.

To get the roll now, undo the yaw and pitch. First, the yaw. Recover $\cos \theta_z$ and $\sin \theta_z$ directly from $\hat n$:

$
\cos \theta_z = \frac {n_x} s \\
\sin \theta_z = \frac {n_y} s
$

Use these to reconstruct $R_z$, then apply $R_z^T$ to $Q$'s left side, leaving $R_y R_x$. Do the same thing with $R_y$, leaving you with just

$R_x = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & & \\
& \cos \theta_x & -\sin \theta_x \\
& \sin \theta_x & \cos \theta_x
\end{bmatrix}
$

The roll can then be determined with one last `atan2`: `roll = atan2(Rx_yy, Rx_yz)`. Again `atan2` is preferred for stability reasons, but also to automatically cover the $\theta_x \notin [-\tau/4, \tau/4]$ case. For slightly better accuracy, you can repeat the roll calculation with the other two non-trivial elements of $R_x$ and do an average.

So, that's all three nautical angles! Though this answers the original question, I feel obligated to add that analysis using these angles suffers from [Gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock), so if you can do your analysis using Q, maybe you should. That or quaternions, spinors, Clifford algebras, or some other kind of posh upper class mathemagicks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming P is [well conditioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Condition_number), you can start with the pseudo-inverse, and compute $T=P'/P$. This should have a form approximately $T=\begin{bmatrix} a_{1,1}&a_{1,2}&a_{1,3}&d_x\\a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}&a_{2,3}&d_y\\a_{3,1}&a_{3,2}&a_{3,3}&d_z\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$. To compute an exact analytical answer, the bottom row of T must be exactly $\begin{matrix}0&0&0&1\end{matrix}$, but if there are only small errors, it may still be possible to calculate an estimated solution that is "good enough" for your purposes using analytical methods.

The values of $d_x$, $d_y$, and $d_z$, are clearly visible in T, so use these to compute $$R_zR_yR_xS=D^{-1}T=D^{-1}P'/P$$.

Next, let $Q=R_zR_yR_x$. Then $$(QS)^TQS=(D^{-1}P'/P)^T(D^{-1}P'/P)$$
$$(QS)^TQS=S^TQ^TQS$$
Note that $Q$ is a rotation matrix, so $Q^TQ=I$, which yields $$(QS)^TQS=S^TIS=S^TS=(D^{-1}P'/P)^T(D^{-1}P'/P)$$
S is a diagonal matrix, so its diagonal elements will equal the square root of the diagonal elements of $(D^{-1}P'/P)^T(D^{-1}P'/P)$.

Now it is possible to compute $Q=D^{-1}TS^{-1}=D^{-1}(P'/P)S^{-1}$. Here [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Euler_angles_.28_z-y.E2.80.99-x.E2.80.B3_intrinsic.29_.E2.86.92_Rotation_matrix) provides the results of the matrix multiplication, $$Q=R_zR_yR_x=\begin{bmatrix} cos(b)cos(c)&cos(a)sin(c)+sin(a)sin(b)cos(c)&sin(a)sin(c)-cos(a)sin(b)cos(c)&0\\-cos(b)sin(c)&cos(a)cos(c)+sin(a)sin(b)sin(c)&sin(a)cos(c)-cos(a)sin(b)sin(c)&0\\sin(b)&-sin(a)cos(b)&cos(a)cos(b)&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Using this array, $b=arcsin(q_{3,1})$, $a=arccos(q_{3,3}/cos(b))$, and $c=arccos(q_{1,1}/cos(b))$.

If you resort to numerical methods, you may also find it useful (depending on the solver) to note that $det(D)=det(R_x)=det(R_y)=det(R_z)=1$ implies $det(S)=det(P'/P)$, and use this as an additional constraint.

Comment: Of course, $D^{-1}T$ is just $T$ with the three $d$’s zeroed out. Once you’ve gotten them out of the way, you can do the rest of this calculation with $3\times3$ matrices, since the last row and column are constant throughout.

Comment: This is a great start. Could you expand - what would make P "nice"? And how would I leverage the determinant relationship that you've shown?

Comment: I tried to explain what I meant by "nice" better... but it basically comes down to "how much error is in your input, and how much error can you accept in your output?" I can muddle my way through the error/stability analysis when I need to, but a qualitative investigation is usually good enough for my purposes, so I'm not the best person to help you with that part.